# python keras neural network: IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds

Tags: python, neural-network, training-data, keras

I was trying to fit a neural network model for multiclass classification but i had the

```
IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds
```

error.
My training data's dimension is `(26728, 450)`, with 450 features. The output size is 5 (5 classes). I used `to_categorical(train_Y)` to transform it to a matrix of 5 columns.

The code is

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=train_X.shape[1], init='uniform'))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, init='uniform'))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(5, init='uniform'))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
    optimizer='sgd', 
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

train_Y_keras = to_categorical(train_Y)
model.fit(train_X, train_Y_keras, nb_epoch=10)
```

I don't fully understand the addition of layers and I copied and modified the code given here http://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#getting-started-with-the-keras-functional-api, can anyone point out my error? Thanks.

Comment: You need to include the complete error and not just one part of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made it work by transforming the pandas dataframe to numpy array.